# what does x-- or x++ do here?

Tags: java

it is a silly Q for most of u - i know - but i one of the beginner here, and I can not understand why the output in here are  12 what does this (`x--`) do to the result ?

```
int x, y;
x = 7;
x-- ;
y = x * 2;
x = 3;
```

Comment: i know this thread is dead but - put a breakpoint on x=7, step through line by line and watch the values of x and y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a cautionary note, sometimes the pre and post increment operators can have unexpected results

[Why does this go into an infinite loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831341/why-does-this-go-into-an-infinite-loop/3831535#3831535)

and what does:

```
x[i]=i++ + 1;
```

do

Read here:
http://www.angelikalanger.com/Articles/VSJ/SequencePoints/SequencePoints.html

Answer (score 13):

`x--` will decrement value of `x` by 1. It is a postfix decrement operator, `--x` is a prefix decrement operator.

So, what's going on here?

```
 
int x, y;    //initialize x and y
x = 7;       //set x to value 7
x--;         //x is decremented by 1, so it becomes 6
y = x * 2;   //y becomes 6*2, therefore y becomes 12
x = 3;       //x becomes 3
```

By analogy, the `++` will increase a value by 1. It also has a prefix and postfix variant.

Answer (score 7):

`x--` subtracts/decrements the value of x by one.

Conversley `x++` adds/increments by one.

The plus or minus signs can either be before (`--x`) or after (`x--`) the variable name, *prefix* and *postfix*. If used in a expression the prefix will return the value after operation has been performed and the postfix will return the value before operation has been performed.

```
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
y = ++x; // y=1, x=1

int x = 0;
int y = 0;
y = x++;// y=0, x=1
```

Comment: If x-- reduces the value of x by one
x = 6 
 y= x*2 
y=12  i got that 
but what are the other x=3 doing here ?

Comment: its assigning the value of 3 to x.

Answer (score 5):

`--` is the 'decrement' operator. It simply means that the variable it operates on (in this case the `x` variable) gets is decremented by 1.

Basically it is shorthand for :

```
x = x - 1;
```

So what the code does :

```
int x,y ; # Define two variables that will hold an integer
x=7;      # Set variable X to value 7
x-- ;     # Decrement x by one : so x equals 7 - 1 = 6
y= x * 2; # Multiply x by two and set the result to the y variable: 6 times 2 equals 12
x=3;      # set x to value 3 (I do not know why this is here).
```

Comment: than x one of the best answer. i guess the 3 here is to confuse the student as it a last year exam Q

Comment: Glad I could help :). If this is part of an exam, this should have been covered in the lessons. This is usualy one of the first things you learn when being introduced to a programming language.

Answer (score 4):

x++ increments x after x being evaluated.
++x increments x before x being evaluated.

```
 int x = 0;
 print(++x); // prints 1
 print(x); // prints 1

 int y = 0;
 print(y++); // prints 0
 print(y); // prints 1
```

The same goes for --

Comment: The title doesn't say so :D. Edited btw.

Comment: @aioobe, the OP asked `x--` **or** `x++` so the answer is valid (but I see that the OP asked specifically `x--`). :)

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
x = 7;
y = --x; /* prefix -- */
```

Here y = 6 (--x reduce x by 1)

```
y = x--; /* postfix -- */
```

Here y = 6 (x-- use first the value of x in the expression and then reduce x by 1)

Answer (score 1):

`x++` is essentially `x = x + 1` (the same applies for `++x`). `x` is incremented by 1.

`x--` is essentially `x = x - 1` (the same applies for `--x`). `x` is decremented by 1.

The difference is that how `x++` and `++x` is used in the statement/expression: In `++x`, `x` is incremented by 1 **first** before being used while in `x++`, `x` is used (before incrementation) **first** and once it's used, it gets incremented by 1.