# Pre and postincrement java evaluation

Tags: java

Could you explain step by step how java evaluates

1) the value of y ?

```
   int x = 5;
   int y = x-- % x++;
```

2) the value of y in this case?

```
   int x = 5;
   int y = x-- * 3 / --x;
```

Comment: duplicate ? [infinite loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4104944/what-does-x-or-x-do-here)
and
[X-- X++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4104944/what-does-x-or-x-do-here)

Comment: So many questions about pre/post increment evaluation!

Comment: unless you are compiler writer, you don't need to know.  There is no good reason to write code that uses ++ and -- in tricky ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the operands are evaluated from left to right, and in each case the result of a *postfix* operation is the value of the variable before the increment/decrement whereas the result of a *prefix* operation is the value of the variable *after* the increment/decrement... so your cases look like this:

Case 1:

```
int x = 5;
int tmp1 = x--; // tmp1=5, x=4
int tmp2 = x++; // tmp2=4, x=5
int y = tmp1 % tmp2; // y=1
```

Case 2:

```
int x = 5;
int tmp1 = x--; // tmp1=5, x=4
int tmp2 = 3;
int tmp3 = --x; // tmp3=3, x=3
int y = tmp1 * tmp2 / tmp3; // y = 5
```

Personally I usually try to avoid using pre/post-increment expressions within bigger expressions, and I'd *certainly* avoid code like this. I find it's almost always clearer to put the side-effecting expressions in separate statements.

Comment: Your explanation is correct. However, does `y` have the same value as yours in case 1 and case 2 if you copy&paste EugeneP's question? Having pre- and postdecrement in one line generally isn't considered a good practise, and I haven't got right now a Java compiler to check results :-/

Comment: @darioo: Yes, it does give the same answers. I agree it's not a good idea though - will edit to mention that.

Comment: Explanation is perfect! And of course, yes, the results are absolutely correct and predictable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about java but in C it evolved into undefined behaviour.

Comment: In Java, the behavior is well-defined, and portable.