# Ajax+JSP is not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp

I want to just show my data from database on div notifications using Ajax 
but it doesn't work. I am using Maven and Spring, 
Hibernate and in this code I am using only JDBC, just to see if it's working or not. But it doesn't give any output.

```
function getNotifications() {
  var xmlHttp;
  try {
    xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  } catch (e) {
    try {
      xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e) {
      alert("your browser cant support");
    }
  }
  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
      var x = (xmlHttp.responseText);
      document.getElementById("notifications").innerHTML = x;
      /* document.write(xmlHttp.responseText); */
    }
  }
  var url = "auto.jsp";
  url = url + "?q=" + str;
  xmlHttp.open("get", url, true);
  xmlHttp.send(url);
}
```

**auto.jsp**

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<% String s="G";
System.out.println("helloooooooooo1111111");
String result=""; 
ArrayList li = new ArrayList();
try {
  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
  Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db2402","root","admin");

  System.out.println("helloooooooooo1111111");
  Statement st = con.createStatement();
  String sql = "select * from message ";
  System.out.println("helloooooooooo22222266666");
  st.execute(sql);

  ResultSet rs = st.getResultSet();

  System.out.println("helloooooooooo222222");
  int i = 1;
  while(rs.next()){
    li.add(rs.getString(i));
    i = i++;
  }
}
catch(Exception ex){
  out.println(ex);
}
%>

<% 
Iterator itr = li.iterator();

while (itr.hasNext()) {
  out.println(itr.next());  
}

%>
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not much of an error description.

Comment: error means when i put alert it this script it doest show the message in block if(xmlHttp.readyState==4){
  var x = (xmlHttp.responseText);
 document.getElementById("notifications").innerHTML= x;
 /* document.write(xmlHttp.responseText); */
 }

Comment: i am using ajax first time soo i dont know how it work but i know this code may be much enough

Comment: @kryger: library/framework/API names like "Maven", "Spring" and "Hibernate" are NOT code. Please do not format them as code in suggested edits!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first look problem seems to be in two statements. You are **reassigning value instead of appending.**
You have `url` variable

```
var url = "auto.jsp";
url = url + "?q=" + str;
```

**Change to**

```
var url = "auto.jsp";
url += "?q=" + str;
```

In `auto.jsp` inside

```
while(rs.next()){
 li.add(rs.getString(i));
 i++; //here simple i++ will work fine.
}
```

---

**Edit**

**Not related:**

1. [how to avoid scriptlets in jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)
2. [preincrement and postincrement in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11629136/preincrement-postincrement-in-java)