# Java - Incrementing a variable before sending to the method

Tags: java, arrays, increment

### Situation

Well, this method is managing a conversion which accepts a list as a parameter, but definately doesn't look *scalable*.

```
List<Long> array_list_data= new ArrayList<>();

public void get_Data() {
    long0 = array_list_data.get(0);
    long1= array_list_data.get(1);
    long2= array_list_data.get(2);
}
```

Afterwards, it will create a different class with the `long` fields.

### Problem

However, what if we have to expand this data to a 100 parameters on this list?

What I have done so far is:

```
List<Long> array_list_data= new ArrayList<>();

public void get_Data() {
    int k = 0;        
    long0= array_list_data.get(k);
    long1= array_list_data.get(k++);
    long2= array_list_data.get(k++);
}
```

Why incrementing `k` is not the right way to do it?

Comment: well, if you have 100 different variables, there's not much you can do, I presume.

Comment: I disagree with the premise of your question.

Comment: use `++k` instead of `k++`

Comment: @kocko His first value is 0. He just needs to add `++` to the first call as well.

Comment: If you had 100 different variables (which is *not* the Java way to hold data), the Java way to manage them would be with 100 different constants holding 100 different index values

Comment: instead of `k++` use `++k`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11629136/preincrement-postincrement-in-java

Comment: Your code is crying for classes and objects (and respect of naming conventions). Why don't you design a class holding all these attributes, instead of storing them as elements at random locations of a list?

Comment: Use a Dictionary (or HashTable) for key-value indexing

Comment: @JBNizet This could actually be a conversion method where raw data is in array format. OP is doing just what you propose.

Comment: @blgt `memory_version` and the other variables are static constants.

Comment: perhaps use a Map, to store variable name as key and variable value as value?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik right. I stand by my comment on naming conventions though

Comment: @JBNizet this is just a conversion method, there's absolutely no randomness at all.

Comment: I'm going with @Jon Skeet 's answer. Although I extremely appreciate all the repercussion, suggests and alternative ways to manage this. I will have to change my code.

Comment: @Holmes: It would be helpful if you'd clarify your question in terms of the conversion - at the moment it looks like both the individual value fields (`max_memory` etc) and the list are fields within the class, which I view as poor modelling. If your code is actually a conversion which accepts a list as a parameter, and then creates a class with the various fields, that's a very different matter.

Comment: Thank you Jon. This is actually a class from my `android` application. I'm pulling data from the `List<Long>` to store each field later in a different class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`k++` performs a *post-increment*. In other words, the value of the expression is the *original* value of `k`, and then `k` is incremented. It's still incremented before the method is called, but the value passed as the argument is the value before the increment takes place. In other words, a call of:

```
x = list.get(k++);
```

is equivalent to:

```
int tmp = k;
k = k + 1;
x = list.get(tmp);
```

So if you actually had:

```
memory_version = array_list_data.get(k++);    // Calls with 0, then k=1
mains_voltage_min = array_list_data.get(k++); // Calls with 1, then k=2
mains_voltage_max = array_list_data.get(k++); // Calls with 2, then k=3
```

then it would be fine, and equivalent to your first code. Your current problem is that you've actually got:

```
memory_version = array_list_data.get(k);      // Calls with 0, then k=0
mains_voltage_min = array_list_data.get(k++); // Calls with 0, then k=1
mains_voltage_max = array_list_data.get(k++); // Calls with 1, then k=2
```

However, I'd suggest that if you're modelling the data *in a class* using a collection as a field, you may well be better off with a separate field for each value. (You may create an *instance* of the class by extracting the data from a list, of course, but that's a different matter.)

Comment: What if there's a file containing the data in array format? This would be just the way to convert into the domain model.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: I would probably read it from the file straight into the domain model: `memoryVersion = stream.readInt();` etc. Currently the OP has the list as a *field*, which doesn't seem like a good plan to me.

Comment: @JonSkeet what could possibly go wrong with listing it as a *field*?

Comment: But the code displayed does look like conversion into a domain model. Whether to do conversion straight away or later depends on a lot of factors beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Possibly. I did say "may not be ideal". It's something the OP should at least *think* about.

Comment: @Holmes: The point is that having a list field is a lot less maintainable (IMO) than having a separate field per value, if you're trying to model "an entity with these various values" as a class.

Comment: But aren't `memory_version`, `mains_voltage_min`, and `mains_voltage_max` just the fields you are suggesting? Note that they are _not_ local variables.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: If that's the case, then the class contains the same data in two different forms, which is even worse! If the question had presented a factory method or constructor *accepting* a `List<Long>` and returning a new instance, I wouldn't have made the comment.

Comment: The difference is major and the advice would be also completely different in that case. If the rest of the logic relies solely on the fields, then we are dealing with just the issue of the lifespan of that arraylist. I strongly disagree with this scenario being "even worse". It is actually much better, with just a small thing to resolve.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: I think we'll have to agree to disagree on this, but I'll clarify my comment.

Comment: My guess is that this is not an actual disagreement, but a difference in the extrapolation to what the rest of the code looks like. I may be too optimistic in my version :)

Answer (score 4):

`k++` will return the value of `k` then increment it.

`++k` will increment `k` then return the incremented value.

You should use `++k` in your situation.

Answer (score 2):

It works fine, just `k++` does first return k and then increment it by one, so you get k, k, k+1, k+2, etc. Use `++k` instead. Or use `k++` in the first call, too, your choice.

Answer (score 2):

Although your approach works fine with some tweaking of `++` position, with 100 fields you may be better off with reflection. Put field names into an array or a list, then go through them one by one in a loop, and set values based on a loop variable:

```
String[] fieldNames = new String[] {"memory_version", " mains_voltage_min", ...};
...
Class<MyClass> c = MyClass.class;
for (int i = 0 ; i != fieldNames.length ; i++) {
    Field f = c.getDeclaredField(fieldNames[i]);
    f.setLong(this, array_list_data.get(i));
}
```

This reduces your list processing code to a few simple lines, and lets you change the order of fields in `array_list_data` simply by arranging your `fieldNames` array in proper order.

Comment: Just rearranging the statements gives the same effect---that's another advantage of using the increment operator.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight can you please provide an example of the `Class<MyClass>`?

Comment: @Holmes Replace `MyClass` with the name of your actual class that holds properties `memory_version`, `mains_voltage_min`, etc. `java.lang.Class<T>` is generic on the class that it represents, so the name of your class needs to come in angular brackets.

Answer (score 1):

To manage scalability, I'd use an enum and a Map:

```
enum Var {
    MEMORY_VERSION(0),
    MAINS_VOLTAGE_MIN(1),
    MAINS_VOLTAGE_MAX(2);

    private Integer value;
    Var(Integer value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Integer value() { return value; }
}

List<Long> array_list_data= new ArrayList<>();
Map<Integer, Long> variables = new HashMap<>();

public void getData() {

    for (int j=0; j<array_list_data.size(); j++) {
        variables.put(j, array_list_data.get(j));
    }

}

public void test() {

    System.out.println("Memory version: " + variables.get(Var.MEMORY_VERSION.value()));
}
```

so that you can add as many vars as you need, and you can retrieve with a meaningful name, like in the test() method.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to maintain the index variable at all; this is why we have iterators:

```
final Iterator<Integer> iterator = array_list_data.iterator();
memory_version = iterator.next();
mains_voltage_min = iterator.next();
mains_voltage_max = iterator.next();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just about the incrementing part, try this:

```
public void getData() {
    int i = 0;        
    // get element 0, then increment i
    memory_version = array_list_data.get(i++);
    // get element 1, then increment i
    mains_voltage_min = array_list_data.get(i++);
    // get element 2, then increment i
    mains_voltage_max = array_list_data.get(i++);
}
```

That's how I do it for example when working with JDBC ResultSet.