# Java confusion: Why is the value of c 8 instead of 9?

Tags: java

I am confused as to why c = 8 and not 9 in the code below.

```
int a = 5, b = 3;
System.out.println(a + b);
int c = a + b++; //
b++;
System.out.println(a + b);
System.out.format("a=%d, b=%d, c=%d %n", a,b,c);
```

Comment: Because `b++` is a post-increment, not a pre-increment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [preincrement / postincrement in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11629136/preincrement-postincrement-in-java)

Answer (score 6):

Post-increment `(b++)` or decrement `(b--)` means read the value first then modify.  Pre-increment`(++b)` or decrement `(--b)`means modify the value then read.

Answer (score 2):

When you say `b++`, you are not saying 'add 1 to `b`, and then use `b`'s new value'. You are saying 'use `b`'s current value for this expression, and then once you are done, add 1 to `b`'.

So in your example, `int c = a + b++`, the current expression is `a + b`. So, for the `a + b`, `b` will give the expression `3`, then increment itself to `4`.

If you want to avoid this issue, you could do `++b` instead of `b++`. `++b` will do exactly what you expect: increment `b`, then use its new value in the expression.

Answer (score 1):

The assignment of `b` is taking place after the statement.

```java
int c = a + b++;
```

This is the same as saying

```java
int c = a + b;
b = b + 1;
```

If you wanted `c` to equal `9`, you can use the prefix unary operator.

```java
int c = a + ++b;
```

Which is the same as saying

```java
b = b + 1;
int c = a + b;
```

[Assignment, Arithmetic, and Unary Operators (The Java™ Tutorials > Learning the Java Language > Language Basics)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html)

Comment: That's a good explanation!

Comment: “after the statement” is misleading at best. Compare with `int c = a + b++ + b++;`…

Comment: @Holger, I'm not sure I understand, can you provide an answer?

Comment: When you try something like `int c = a + b++ + b++;` you’ll notice that the second `b` will evaluate to the updated value of the first `b++`. In other words, the `b` is not updated “after the statement” as other parts of the expression can see the already updated value. You should rather consider an expression like `b++` to be similar to calling `set(index, value)` on a `List` which will change the list immediately but return the old value.

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of increment Operators :

1. Post increment : (b++), which states that it will use the value first and then increment.
2. Pre Increment : (++b), which states that it will first increment the value and then use it.

In your case you are using `b++` hence, it first use the value of b, i.e. 3, and then updates 3 -> 4, and again you are using `b++`, again it update the value to 4 -> 5. Hence its new value is 5 and in c it used the previous value not updated.