# What does array[++variable] stand for?

Tags: java, arrays, iteration

Sample code here:

```
static class stack 
{
    int top=-1;
    char items[] = new char[100];

    void push(char x) 
    {
        if (top == 99)
            System.out.println("Stack full");
        else
            items[++top] = x;
    }
}
```

What exactly happens when items[++top] occurs?

Comment: What part of the code is not clear? Is it the `items[...]` syntax or the `++top` syntax? Or both?

Comment: Look up `pre-increment` and `post-increment` to explain the `++top`. [Here is a link to Java docs for arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html)

Comment: [What does x-- or x++ do here?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4104944) [What is the difference between a += b and a =+ b , also a++ and ++a?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5098282) [Assignment, Arithmetic, and Unary Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's pre incrementation. It's equal to:

```
void push(char x) 
    {
        if (top == 99)
            System.out.println("Stack full");
        else {
            top = top + 1;
            items[top] = x;
        }

    }
```

Comment: It is pre increment

Comment: oh yeah I've realised that just after posting, my bad.

Comment: The curly brace for the else block is missing

Comment: You're right, I've added it.

Answer (score 2):

This called **Pre-increment**, so this `items[++top] = x;` equivalent to :

```
top++; // this also equivalent to top+=1; or top = top + 1;
items[top] = x;
```