# Increment Operator Magic in C#

Tags: c#, increment, post-increment, pre-increment

Why is the Output of this code gives the value 100. Please help me to understand this behavior.

```
static void Main(string[] args)  
{  
    int i = 100;  
    for (int n = 0; n < 100; n++)  
    {  
         i = i++;  
    }  
    Console.WriteLine(i);  // This gives the Value 100 why?
}
```

I have ran the same code in both C and C# compiler.
in C compiler gives the value 200
in C# compiler gives the value 100.

why the same piece of code is behaving like this in two Compilers?

Comment: There are thousands of duplicates of this question.

Comment: [This is a more suitable duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6716189/i-i-doesnt-increment-i-why)

Answer (score 2):

This is the same as

```
static void Main(string[] args)  
{  
    int i = 100;  
    for (int n = 0; n < 100; n++)  
    {  
       int x = i;
       i++;
       i = x;  
    }  
    Console.WriteLine(i);  // This gives the Value 100 why?
}
```

You reassign the 100 all the time in the loop

Answer (score 0):

Because it is post increment. First 100 will be assigned then incremented.

i = i++;

hence the output.

Comment: After assign the value is should Increment i right.? why that is not happening.... the same code I have executed in C compiler also. I am getting the value 200. Waht is the difference?