# Insert a charcter in an array string periodically

Tags: java, arrays, string

I wrote a method to insert a character in an string array periodically.
I wrote it in android studio, and the application stops running. 
My input is an array of string: (The part of input is just for test, and I will make it dynamic)

```
    String[] myPoints= new String[4];
    myPoints[0]="22";
    myPoints[1]="45";
    myPoints[2]="34";
    myPoints[3]="60";
```

Now I need to insert ", " between each two records of array. So I wrote this:

```
public static String[] insertPeriodically(String[] points){


    int pointsSize = points.length;// length of points array
    int withCommosSize=pointsSize+(pointsSize/2)-1;//length of new array
    String[] withCommos= new String[withCommosSize];
    int insert=0;
    int k=0;
    for (int i=0; i<pointsSize; i=i++){
        withCommos[k]=points[i];
        insert=insert+1;
        if(insert==2){
            withCommos[k+1]=",";
            k++;
            insert=0;
        }else
        k++;
    }
    return withCommos;
}
```

The console shows this java error: 
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfojava.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=5; index=5

Do you have any suggestion where is the problem?

Comment: Did you try changing this `int withCommosSize=pointsSize+(pointsSize/2)-1` to  `int withCommosSize=pointsSize+(pointsSize-1)`

Comment: `and the application stops running` why? an exception? If so - please add a complete stack trace.

Comment: IndexOutOfBoundException is fairly clear... Why not use an array that grows with the data, like a List?

Comment: It stops running because of this method, because when I comment it, it works.

Comment: Why not use an array that grows with the data, like a List? You meant an array list?

Answer (score 1):

There's a typo in your for loop (`i=i++`), and you should always increment k at least once. This works:

```
public static String[] insertPeriodically(String[] points){
    int pointsSize = points.length;// length of points array
    int withCommosSize=pointsSize+(pointsSize/2)-1;//length of new array
    String[] withCommos= new String[withCommosSize];
    int insert=0;
    int k=0;
    for (int i=0; i<pointsSize; i++){
        withCommos[k]=points[i];
        insert=insert+1;
        if(insert==2 && k<withCommosSize-1){
            withCommos[k+1]=",";
            k++;
            insert=0;
        }
        k++;
    }
    return withCommos;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be how about this

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i=0;i<points.length;i++)
            {
                list.add(points[i]);
                if(i==(points.length-1)) break;
                list.add(",");
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

`Unable to start activity ComponentInfojava.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:`

You are getting this exception because of `i=i++`. Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6716189/i-i-doesnt-increment-i-why)

This statement will not increase the value of `i` but you are increasing value of `k` every time(using `if` or `else`). Since `i` is not increasing your `for` loop will run in infinite-loop. And once value of `k` is greater than `withCommosSize` you will get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Change `i=i++` to `i++` and It will work.

Comment: Thank you, i did it and it runs now!