# Correct way to change value in List<int> / array

Tags: c#, .net

Suppose the List/array

```
List<int> a = new List<int>(){1,2,3,4,5};
int []a = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5};
```

And I want to change the value at index 2, whats the correct way?

```
a[2]++; or a[2] = a[2]++;
```

Please explain the answer.

Comment: Have you actually tried them out and observed the effects?

Comment: Have you considered `++a[2]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of `a[2] = a[2]++` will be `a[2]`, in this case 3.

The [postfix increment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#increment-operator-) `a[2]++` will change the value of `a[2]` *after* the line in which it appears has finished.

If you want to change the value, then `a[2]++` or `a[2] = ++a[2]` are valid.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is the first one:

```
A[2]++;
```

The second one also works but it does more work than necessary. It is equivalent to the following code:

```
a[2] = a[2]; // useless
a[2]++;
```

The *suffix* ++ operator (as in `x++`) applies after the line in which it appears has finished executing. The *prefix* ++ operator (as in `++x`) first modifies the element and then uses the value.

I suggest you read the documentation about the "increment operator":

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#increment-operator-

Comment: "*The second one also works*" [Nope, it doesn't.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6716189/87698)