# Something is wrong with Enum++

Tags: c#, .net, enums, .net-6.0

I have Interface `IStateMachine<T>` (that succession from other interface, `IStateMachine`), the successor class from `IStateMachine<T>` and enum `AddItemEnum`. Example code:

```
interface IStateMachine
{
    void MoveNext(string text);
}

interface IStateMachine<T> : IStateMachine
{
    T State {get;set;}
}

enum AddItemEnum
{
    None, AddName, AddDescription
}

class AddItemCounter : IStateMachine<AddItemEnum>
{
    public AddItemEnum State {get;set;}

    public void MoveNext(string text) => State = State++;
}
```

What is my problem: when I incrementing `State` property, I don't getting incremented enum value, but if I restart app, problem disappears. Why?:) I don't understand this

*It's only example of code*

I tried to use this piece of shhh... code, but it works: `State = (AddSellProgress)((int)State + 1);`

Comment: `State++` increments state, but returns the value before incrementing. This is then assigned to `State` again, so all in all, `State` does not change.

Comment: @KlausGütter is correct, you want `public void MoveNext(string text) => State++;`, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/lW6PEi.  See [What is the difference between i++ and ++i in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3346729) and [i = i++ doesn't increment i. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6716217).

Comment: @KlausGütter Thanks, now it works stable.

Comment: @dbc Thanks! Enum in this case has nothing to do with it, only my incorrect understanding of the ++ operator is to blame here;