# post Increment problem

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does this go into an infinite loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831341/why-does-this-go-into-an-infinite-loop)

```
public class loop
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int k=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) 
        {
            k = k++;
            System.out.println(k);            
        }
    }
}
```

out put :

```
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

Can You Please explain me why above resulting zeros even am incrementing k value and assigning it to k.

Answer (score 8):

This line is a no-op:

```
k = k++;
```

It's equivalent to:

```
int tmp = k;
k = k + 1;
k = tmp;
```

You're incrementing `k`, but then assigning the *original* value back to `k`.

I hope you don't *really* have code like that... while the behaviour of this code is well-defined in Java, it's (clearly) confusing.

Answer (score 0):

may be your are trying to get something like

```
int k=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) 
    {
        k = ++k;
        System.out.println(k);            

    }
```

Comment: I think `++k;` is better than `k = ++k;`

Comment: thanks for your reply. But i wanted know why k is  not incrementing.

Answer (score 0):

You can even better use:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Comment: i wanted to know reason behind that.                           public class loop                                                  {                                                               public static void main(String[] rgs)                               { int k=0,j=0; for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)                          { j= k++; System.out.println(k+" "+j); } } }

Answer (score 0):

The `k++` piece of code increments the value of k by 1 and then returns the pre-incremented value. Thus, the following line:

```
k = k++;
```

adds one to k, and then assigns the original value of k (returned by k++) to k. This means k winds up with it's original value.

```
public class loop {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int k=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            k++; // increments k by 1
            System.out.println(k);            
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class loop
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int k=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) 
        {
            k++; // k increased. No reasons to assign anything
            System.out.println(k);            
        }
    }
 }
```

`k++` increase `k`, then return **old** `k` , then you asign this **old** `k` to `k` and `k` is 0 again