# Can someone explain this output in java?

Tags: java

I ran the following code snippet

```
int n=0;
for(int m=0;m<5;m++){
n=n++;
System.out.print(n)}
```

I got the output as 00000 when i expected 01234. Can someone explain why

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have seen same question some time before.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does this go into an infinite loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831341/why-does-this-go-into-an-infinite-loop)

Comment: Its been asked many times as it a difference between Java and C++. http://www.google.com/search?q=x+x%2B%2B+in+java 452,000 results

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`n=n++;` should be just `n++;` or `n=n+1;` (or even `n=++n;` if you want)

`n++` does the increment but will return the value of `n` before the increment took place. So in this case you're incrementing `n`, but then setting `n` to be the value before the increment took place, effectively meaning `n` doesn't change.

The `++` operator can either be used as prefix or postfix. In postfix form (`n++`) the expression evaluates to `n`, but in the prefix case (`++n`) the expression will evaluate to `n+1`. Just using them on their own has the same outcome though, in that `n`'s value will increment by 1.

Comment: so does then increment happen first and then the assignment? why is that?

Comment: @Kaushik You have it the wrong way around. For n=n++, the assignment is first, then the increment. For n=++n, the increment would happen first, then the assignment. If you just want to increment n, use n++ on it's own.

Answer (score 4):

`n = n++` increments `n`, then sets `n` to the value it had before you incremented it. Use either:

```
n++;
```

or

```
n = n + 1;
```

but don't try to do both at once. It doesn't work.

Comment: please correct the following:
I am under the impression that when i write n=n++, the initial value of n (which is 0) is assigned to the LHS and then n++ happens which increments n to 1. 

Why doesn't this happen . What am i missing?

Comment: @Kaushik In the expression n=n++, (n++) is evaluated and assigned to n. n++ increments n, but evaluates to the value of n before the increment. So (n++) would increment n to 1, but evaluate to the value of n before the increment, in this case 0. The statement then becomes n=0. You're assigning n to itself, the increment is lost.

Comment: You could think of it as if there were three operations happening. One, the value of n is put into holding. Two, the value of n is incremented. Three, the value in holding is assigned to n. hold=n; n++; n=hold; I think the reason for this is the method that Javascript uses to assign variables. In c++, n=n++ works because it doesn't assign it to a holding variable, but instead assigns and increments the value directly.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a ++, the operator can either be BEFORE or AFTER the variable.  Likewise, the addition will occur before or after the operand is executed.  If the line were to have read:

```
n = ++n;
```

Then it would have done what you would have expected it to do.

Comment: It would also be redundant. ++n already changes the value of n, there's no need to then assign it to n.

Answer (score 0):

```
n = ++n;
```

would also work :-) But it is useless to assign a variable to itself. In order to increment n, just use

```
n++;
```

or

```
++n;
```

Comment: `n = n++` doesn't "also work". But in contrast, yes, everything else here does work.

Answer (score 0):

Java uses value of a variable in the next instance on post increment.

In the code snippet, the loop execute for the first time picks up n=0 and increments at the operand. But the incremented value will be reflected on next occurrence of n not in current assignment hence 0 will be set to n one more time. I think this is because n=n++ is ATOMIC operation.

So the n is set 0 always.

To avoid this either you do pre-increment [++n] or +1 [n+1] where your reference get updated immediately.

Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Since it doesn't seem to have been mentioned previously, you can also use

```
n += 1;
```

if you really like assignment operators.