# Why output is 0?

Tags: java

```
class T {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int x = 0;
        x = x++;
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: See if this helps explain http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094872/is-there-a-difference-between-x-and-x-in-java

Comment: The answers below give the reason. If you want to know more than the reason and actually need a solution as well, use the prefix operator: `++x`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does this go into an infinite loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831341/why-does-this-go-into-an-infinite-loop)

Answer (score 8):

Because `++` is the "post increment" operator - it returns the value of the variable *before* it gets incremented.

The steps are:

- Take the value of `i` (before incrementing it) and remember it
- Increment `i`
- Assigned the remembered value to `i`

Comment: Thanks RichieHindle ! Good explanation !

Comment: @user989093 be sure to use the green checkmark on the answer that best suited your question.

Answer (score 4):

Because the post increment operator returns a temporal value (`x`´s current value) and then increments x.

Try it like this:

```
class T {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int x = 0;
        x = ++x;
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: Or just `x++`, without the `x =` part. :)

Answer (score 3):

```
x = x++;
```

is equivalent to

```
 temp = x;

 x = x + 1;

 x = temp;
```

That's why the output is zero.

This operator is known as **post increment** operator.
Other operator related  to post increment operator is, **per-increment** operator.

```
x = ++x;
```

If you apply **per-increment** output will be 1.

Answer (score 2):

Because you've used a postfix `++` operator, which means it's evaluated after the assignment. So first `x = x` is evaluated, so `x` stays as `0`, and then `x++` is evaluated, but the result is not assigned to anything.

You could use the prefix `++` operator to achieve your desired result: `x = ++x;`

From the [docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html):

> The increment/decrement operators can be applied before (prefix) or
>   after (postfix) the operand. The code result++; and ++result; will
>   both end in result being incremented by one. The only difference is
>   that the prefix version (++result) evaluates to the incremented value,
>   whereas the postfix version (result++) evaluates to the original
>   value.

Answer (score 1):

`x++` returns zero and then increments x.  The assignment `x = x++` sets `x` (after it has been incremented) to the return value of `x++`, which was 0.

Answer (score 0):

because ++ after is add after the program runs. you can fix it by the following two ways

```
class T {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int x = 0;
        x = ++x;
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

or

```
class T {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int x = 0;
        x += 1;
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because `x++` effectively means, "use the value stored in `x` and then increment it". If you want to increment the value before you use it, do `++x` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I don't now that it will make a difference in the output, but you don't need the import and you can change:

```
x = x++;
```

to:

```
x++;
```

Answer (score 0):

Showing example of post increment with regular increment, as previous answerers said:

```
class T { 
    public static void main(String args[]) { 
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
          int x = 0; 
          x = x+1+i; 
          System.out.println(x); 
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first result of [this](https://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&q=java%20increment%20assignment#hl=en&safe=off&q=java%20increment%20assignment%20x%20=%20x%2b%2b&pbx=1&oq=java%20increment%20assignment%20x%20=%20x%2b%2b) search is [this](http://www.rizzoweb.com/java/postfixIncrement.html) link.

> The reason it behaves as observed is because of the interaction
>   between the operator precedence and the odd "return value" of the ++
>   operator. The postfix increment happens first (see your favorite copy
>   of the operator precedence chart); but postfix, by definition, returns
>   the previous value of the variable. So that "return value" is not
>   "original x plus one", but instead just "original x" (x, at this
>   point, actually contains the incremented value). This returned value
>   is then assigned to x, which overwrites what the ++ did in the first
>   place. IOW, in the expression x=x++, the incremented value is lost,
>   overwritten by the assignment that happens last.

Google is your friend! :)

Answer (score 0):

Explanation of what you are doing:

```
class T {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int x = 0; // x is zero
        x = x++;  // assign x to be x (which is 0). 
                 //  then increment a non-existant variable by 1
        System.out.println(x); //print 0
    }
}
```