# Postfix concept

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is x after “x = x++”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911776/what-is-x-after-x-x)

I am shocked to see this output and want to know how it is working internally please help me.

```
int i=0;
i = i++;
System.out.println(i);
i=i++;
System.out.println(i);
```

Output is 0 and 0.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831341/why-does-this-go-into-an-infinite-loop Read this.

Answer (score 1):

Change it to

```
int i=0;
i++;//note the removed i =
System.out.println(i);
i++;//note the removed i =
System.out.println(i);
```

and it will work as expected

See the [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html) and their [demo code](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/examples/PrePostDemo.java), and to quote the most relevant part

> The increment/decrement operators can be applied before (prefix) or after (postfix) the operand. The code result++; and ++result; will both end in result being incremented by one. The only difference is that the prefix version (++result) evaluates to the incremented value, whereas the postfix version (result++) evaluates to the original value. If you are just performing a simple increment/decrement, it doesn't really matter which version you choose. But if you use this operator in part of a larger expression, the one that you choose may make a significant difference.

Comment: Just tried to run the code from the question in my IDE (IntelliJ) and it warns me even about the fact that the result of i++ is never used

Comment: Thanks Robin, i got answer from your comment and [janeg.ca/scjp/oper/prefix.html].