# Why does this cause an infinite loop

Tags: java, post-increment

Consider this simple code:

```
 // E1 
  public void doTest(String pattern) {
    int counter = 0;

    while (counter < 3) {
        counter = counter++;
    }
    System.out.println("Done");
}
```

This causes an infinite loop.

However if the statement that increments the counter is written like this:

```
E2.  counter = ++counter;
```

or this

```
E3.    counter++;
```

It terminates normally.   I understand that the incrementing occurs after the assignment in the version that fails which explains why E2 works,  but I thought java assigned the results of an increment in the variable that is incremented as in E3.    So I'm perplexed as to why E1 fails but E3 does not.

Comment: Do you know how to use a dubugger? This is a great tool which can help you understand how code like this works.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831341/why-does-this-go-into-an-infinite-loop?rq=1

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a difference between x++ and ++x in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094872/is-there-a-difference-between-x-and-x-in-java)

Answer (score 17):

```
counter = counter++;
```

The above code has no effect on `counter`. It is effectively same as:

```
int temp = counter;
counter++;
counter = temp;
```

So, the value of `counter` is not changing at all.

On the other hand, if you use:

```
counter = ++counter;
```

The counter is incremented first, and then is re-assigned to counter. Essentially, you can simply ignore the assignment part, and keep it simply this:

```
counter++; // Or ++counter
```

Comment: @Elliott, you can further understand this by reading up on post and pre increments here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Increment_and_decrement_operators

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the value of `counter` at the end of the loop body is the same as it was at the beginning.  The statement `counter = counter++` is equivalent to:

```
int temp = counter;
counter = counter + 1;
counter = temp;
```

The `postIncrement++` operator returns the value before the increment; the `++preIncrement` operator returns the incremented value.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
 counter = counter++;
```

by:
1)

```
counter+=1;
```

or

2)

```
counter++;
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It is better to avoid this kind assignment.
The `++` is intended to be used by itself. If you want to increment by yourself you could have done `counter += 1`.