# Unexpected output from while loop Java

Tags: java

This is the class whose behaviour I am unable to understand.

```
class loop1 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int i = 10;

        do
            while(i++ < 15) {
                System.out.println(i);
                i = i + 20;
                System.out.println(i);
            } 
        while(i<2);

        System.out.println(i);    
    }

}
```

I expected it to print

```
11
31
31
```

But it prints

```
11
31
32
```

I am not able to understand why this "32" has come up in the output.

This is my understanding of the flow

- i = 10
- In the while loop because of unary incremental, it becomes 11 so this explains the first output
- 11 gets incremented to 31 by (+20)
- Then 31 < 15 should fail (during the next iteration) so it should proceed to the last print statement and print 31, but it instead it is printing 32.

Can someone tell me what I am missing ?

Comment: For the same reason the first print statement print `11`. `31` is increment before the last print statement is executed.

Comment: Thanks Rohit.You could have put this as answer..would have upvoted it :)

Comment: You're welcome :) Well, there are already 3 duplicate answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does this go into an infinite loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831341/why-does-this-go-into-an-infinite-loop)

Answer (score 5):

During the final evaluation of the first while loop `i++` still increments `i` even though the loop does not execute because the condition fails.

```
class loop1 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        //1.  i = 10
        int i = 10;

        do 
            // 2. while loop condition = (10 < 15), i = 11
            // 6. while loop condition = (31 < 15), i = 32
            while(i++ < 15) {
                System.out.println(i);  //3. prints 11
                i = i + 20; //4. i = 31
                System.out.println(i);  //5. prints 31
            } 

        while(i<2); //this really has no effect on the codes execution, given i values

        System.out.println(i); //7.  Prints 32
    }

}
```

Comment: [i++ increments by 1 but returns the original value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831341), so the comparison check in 6 is `31 < 15` but `i == 32`.

Comment: @fommil the expression evaluates 31 < 15, but after the evaluation `i++` still increments i to 32.  I think we are on the same page here.

Comment: yes, I was suggesting a minor improvement to your comments ;-)

Answer (score 3):

```
i++
```

You're increasing the value by 1. The value, when you increase it after the first iteration is `31`. `31 + 1` is, surprisingly, `32`. And you print out the value directly after incrementing it.

Answer (score 2):

In 2nd iteration when condition of while loop is check
`while(i++<15)`
at that time `i is 31` so condition fail but `i++` change the value of `i 31 -> 32`

Answer (score 2):

`while(i++ < 15)` compare the value of i with and after that increment i by 1

Answer (score 1):

My guess is:

```
while(i++ < 15)
```

The `i++` increments the value from 31 to 32 on the second loop.

Note, the `++` will be executed even if the condition fails - which in your case, the 31 is greater than 15 (condition fails), however because of the `++` the value is incremented to 32, which is being printed out by the `System.out` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

In the program :

```
 while(i++<15)
```

above statement is condition checking in this statement
you are post increment i therefor 31+1=32 is comming