# Why does this code goes into infinite loop?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

Consider the following code :

```
public class Game {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int x = 0;
        while (x < 1) {
          x = x++;
        }

    }

}
```

With my compiler this code goes into infinite loop , but why ?

First , we place the value of `x` into `x` , and **only** then we add 1 to `x` , and afterwards I would expect that `1 < 1` would be false , and the while loop would terminate ...

But no , that doesn't happen .

So what might be the reason for the infinite loop ?

Comment: Sounds like an excellent question for a debugger.  Step through it.  Or put some log statements in there.

Comment: `x=x++;` leaves `x` unchanged - you increment it, and THEN replace it with the OLD value (the value before you incremented).

Comment: -1 for not checking out "Related" (second question there contains the answer)

Comment: In particular, you seem to be confused when you say, "First, we place the value of x into x, and only then we add 1 to x". It is true that lexically the assignment is before the increment, but the value on the right-hand side of the assignment must be calculated before the assignment can occur. (And that value is the *old* value of x, since the increment is a *post*-increment).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The expression `x++` is a post-increment, meaning that it the value of the expression is the old value, `0`, which is then assigned back to `x`, so `x` is always `0` after `x = x++;`.

To break out of the infinite loop, don't assign it back to `x`, leaving the post-increment value of `x`, `1`, intact:

```
while (x < 1) {
   x++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`x++` is pretty much equivalent to

```
some-temporary = x;
x = x + 1;
now use the value of some-temporary
```

So `x = x++;` is equivalent to

```
some-temporary = x;
x = x + 1;
x = some-temporary;
```

so you should be able to see why the part that adds 1 has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

That is beacause `x` gets incremented *after being used*. So the expanded sequence of operations taking place would be:

1. `oldX = x`
2. `x++`, that is, `x = x + 1`
3. `x = oldX`

`oldX` being a fictitious variable.

What happens is that `x` is always assigned `oldX`, which in our case is `0`, resulting in an infinite loop. The `x++` part is just ignored.

Solution: replace `x = x++` with `x++` or, if you *really* want, `x = ++x`.

Answer (score 0):

`x = x++` doesn't do what you want. Replace it with `x++`.

`x++` is equivalent to `x = x + 1`, so your assignment doesn't make sense.

More information about this can be found in answers here:

[Why does this go into an infinite loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831341/why-does-this-go-into-an-infinite-loop/3831945#3831945)

Comment: I meant exactly that : `x = x++;`

Comment: @ron it is the same as t = x + 1; x = x;

Comment: No, @ron, you mean `x = x + 1;`, however you choose to write it.